# Change disabled QCalendarWidget weekends color

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I want to customize `QCalendarWidget` and I can't change the weekends colors for the disabled state. This is how it looks right now:

[image]

I would like to gray out the red. I know that you can set the weekends colors with:

```
QTextCharFormat weekendFormat;
weekendFormat.setForeground(QBrush(Qt::green, Qt::SolidPattern));
m_ui->calendarWidget->setWeekdayTextFormat(Qt::Saturday, weekendFormat);
m_ui->calendarWidget->setWeekdayTextFormat(Qt::Sunday, weekendFormat);
```

but this doesn't affect the disabled state. How can I affect the disabled state and set different disabled colors for the weekend?

Thanks!

Comment: I use Qt 4.6.2 and your code works fine for me.

Comment: @hank The code changes the colors for the *enabled* state. Are the red colors changing also for the *disabled* state?

Comment: yes, new color applies for disabled items too.

Comment: yes, but I would like to have different colors for the disabled and enabled state. is this possible without reimplementing the paint event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get different colors for enabled and disabled states, you can subclass and reimplement the change event handler:

```
void MyCalendar::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    QCalendarWidget::changeEvent(event);
    if (event->type() == QEvent::EnabledChange)
    {
        QColor color;

        if (isEnabled())
        {
            color = Qt::blue;
        }
        else
        {
            color = Qt::yellow;
        }

        QTextCharFormat weekendFormat;
        weekendFormat.setForeground(QBrush(color, Qt::SolidPattern));
        setWeekdayTextFormat(Qt::Saturday, weekendFormat);
        setWeekdayTextFormat(Qt::Sunday, weekendFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i think it's not possible to have it without reimplementing `QCalendarWidget`... so this is the solution